# ASP.NET Core Invalid Password Reset Tokens

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-identity

I have two servers that are using the same ASP.NET Core Identity backend. I generate the password reset token with the following:

```
var token = await _userManager.GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync(applicationUser);
```

I send this token via an email link. When the user clicks the link, they are taken to a separate site which should provide a UI to change the password. The following code handles the user's password submission of both the token and their new password:

```
var identityResult = await _userManager.ResetPasswordAsync(applicationUser, code, password);
```

On the second server, the identity result always returns false because "invalid token".

Looking through the source, I see that the token is generated using the IP address (so I understand why the token validation failed).

My question is how do I enable successful token creation/validation across different machines? In previous forms of ASP.NET, I would likely use a shared machine key to prevent these scenarios. ASP.NET Core doesn't seem to have a similar concept. From what I've read, it seems that this might be a scenario to use the DataProtection API. Unfortunately, I haven't seen any examples as how to apply this to generating the reset token.

Comment: Not sure if this carries over from older version but you need to set the machine keys so they encrypt the tokens the same way

Comment: Core doesn't appear to have a concept of machine keys (at least not in the web.config).

Comment: @Eric did you ever figure this out? I have the exact issue happening

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried setting the application name to the same value in both applications?

```
services.AddDataProtection().SetApplicationName("same for both apps");
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/configuration/overview

P.S - I'm struggling with exactly the same problem.

Comment: @user1015196, yes. The best way for me was to persist the keys to the file system and have all app instances point to the exact same location.

Comment: I would that as well, but my app runs in different Docker containers, thus different file systems so this solution doesn't work for me. I need something to persist the keys in the database and retrieve from there.

Answer (score 4):

you should encode your token before you send it. You should do something like this:

```
var token = await _userManager.GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync(applicationUser);
var encodedCode = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(token);
```

After encoding it, you must pass the encoded token rather than the generated token.

Comment: Works for me using .net core 2.0

Answer (score 0):

I faced the similar problem. Its not about 2 servers actually. Its about identity framework. You can derived from usermanager and you can override provider with central one. But I tried something different and it worked. 
First of all ConfirmEmail method looks into database, if you have one database the shouldn't be a problem between tokens with more than one server.

In your usermanager you should create dataprovider at your constructor like this.

```
 public ApplicationUserManager(IUserStore<ApplicationUser> store)
            : base(store)
        {
            var dataProtectorProvider = Startup.DataProtectionProvider;
            var dataProtector = dataProtectorProvider.Create("My Identity");
            this.UserTokenProvider = new DataProtectorTokenProvider<ApplicationUser, string>(dataProtector);
            //this.UserTokenProvider.TokenLifespan = TimeSpan.FromHours(24);
        }
```

Also you should be see token in your database table for users. After this line of code.

```
    string code = await UserManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user.Id);
    var callbackUrl = Url.Action("ConfirmEmail", "Account", new { userId = user.Id, code = code }, protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);
    UserManager.EmailService = new EmailService();
    await UserManager.SendEmailAsync(user.Id, "Confirm your account", "Please confirm your account by clicking <a href=\"" + callbackUrl + "\">here</a>");
```

When you see token in your database, check email for same. then click you callback url and correct the encode of url.

For using dataProtectorProvider ;

```
public partial class Startup
    {
      public static IDataProtectionProvider DataProtectionProvider { get; set; }

        public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {
           DataProtectionProvider = app.GetDataProtectionProvider();
        }
}
```

Comment: Where did you define Startup.DataProtectionProvider? It's not there by default? Does your Startup class inherit from some base class, or did you define the DataProtectionProvider property yourself?

Comment: I'm not sure if this applies, I'm also using identity server and you would have to change all of your authentication to have a centralized token server.

Comment: With that being said you could just use one server for authentication and make cors requests to it and trust that the token you receive is valid,  with out having to switch to identity server

Comment: I defined at startup class like this,
public static IDataProtectionProvider DataProtectionProvider { get; set; }

Comment: @orhun.begendi What did you initialize your DataProtectionProvider with?

Comment: @orhun.begendi It appears you are using .NET 4.5? I am attempting to do this using .NET Core. I don't have the IAppBuilder interface or the GetDataProtectionProvider extension method.

Comment: its on dotnet core, identity framework is the same on core and .net 4.5. You can check details on tokenprovider on github 
https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity/UserManager.cs

Comment: @orhun.begendi I am trying to understand how to configure the applications to use the same token provider, but your above code makes use of UserManager.UserTokenProvider, IAppBuilder, and GetDataProtectionProvider (which don't exist in ASPNET Core).